# CAF: subtitles positioning issue even after shaka-player update

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, ttml, shaka, caf-receiver-sdk

We've created a custom CAF v3 receiver. We had the same troubles as those described here (subtitles in the top-left corner of the screen) [CAF Receiver: Positioning of subtitles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210076/caf-receiver-positioning-of-subtitles) . 
Looks like Google managed to fix this issue in shaka-player v2.2.10. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71890891 .However, **even after** Google updated its caf library reference to shaka-player.js v2.2.10, we're still experiencing subtitle positioning issues. Here's an example of ttml.

ttml:

```
<tt xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:tt="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" xmlns:ttm="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#metadata" >
<head>
  <styling>
   <style xml:id="speakerStyle" tts:fontFamily="proportionalSansSerif" tts:fontSize="4%" tts:textAlign="center" tts:displayAlign="after" tts:color="white" tts:textOutline="black 2px 0px" tts:backgroundColor="transparent" />
  </styling>
  <layout>
   <region xml:id="speaker" tt:style="speakerStyle" tts:origin="10% 5%" tts:extent="90% 90%" tts:zIndex="1" /> 
  </layout>
</head>
<body timeContainer="par">
  <div xml:lang="und">
   <p xml:id="c456f80_00" xml:space="preserve" begin="0.000000s" end="0.680000s" region="speaker" tts:backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,128)" >No podemos relacionar</p>
   <p xml:id="c456f80_01" xml:space="preserve" begin="0.000000s" end="0.680000s" region="speaker" tts:backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,128)" >a Rutledge con el asesinato.</p>
  </div>
  <div xml:lang="und">
   <p xml:id="c456f80_02" xml:space="preserve" begin="0.920000s" end="2.000000s" region="speaker" tts:backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,128)" >Cuando estuve en Chechenia</p>
   <p xml:id="c456f80_03" xml:space="preserve" begin="0.920000s" end="2.000000s" region="speaker" tts:backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,128)" >identificando cadÃ¡veres,...</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm not sure but I suspect that the **tts:origin** in the region "speaker" here may be the cause. 
Is there anyone still experiencing the same issue even after google's reference update? Are there any alternatives in order to custom subtitles positioning?

Comment: Please file a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the tts:origin attribute of the "speaker" region - it should be positioning the region top left at 10% across from the left and 5% down from the top. However you've set tts:displayAlign on the style, when it only applies to the region, so the default of "before" will apply instead of "after" which you might be expecting. This means that the text will be aligned at the top of the region instead of the bottom. Try moving the setting of tts:displayAlign to the region element and see if that helps.